# How to get next page outcomes for only the pages that have it?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So this code gets me all the match outcomes, team a vs team and score of the match. For example a team like this http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/7395-mousesports-cs/matches. But this code only gets the first page outcomes, I'm trying to get all the outcomes of every page that's available. The problem is some teams don't have a next page button, so the program crashes when I tried to implement that code. How would I write the code to obtain the next page and continue obtaining the outcomes, and if a team match link doesn't have a next page just continue?

```
def all_match_outcomes():
    for match_outcomes in match_history_url():
        rest_server(True)
        page = requests.get(match_outcomes).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        team_name_element = soup.select_one('div.teamNameHolder')
        team_name = team_name_element.find('h1').text.replace('- Team Overview', '')

        for match_outcome in soup.select('table.simple.gamelist.profilelist tr'):
            opp1 = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'opp1'}).text
            opp2 = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'opp2'}).text

            opp1_score = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'hscore'}).text
            opp2_score = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'ascore'}).text

            if match_outcome(True):  # If teams have past matches
                print(team_name, '%s %s:%s %s' % (opp1, opp1_score, opp2_score, opp2))
```

Comment: What is an example of a no next button? are you talking about the next button at the end of the page or what exactly?

Comment: So on the link at the bottom it'll show the number of pages and then next page or last page..some teams don't have that at all because they don't have many games played or whatever the case may be. So if I incorporate a code that will get me the next page it'll crash and say that the page does not contain said tag or whatever I'm using to find the next page.

Answer (score 0):

After the `for` loop that pulls the game scores out of the table you can grab the pagination links.

With this code you can grab the very next page by finding the currently selected page. If there isn't a page beyond the currently selected it (currently) will print "no page found".

```
paginate = soup.find('div', {'class':'paginator'})

page = paginate.find('a', {'class':'selected'})

next_page = page.find_next_sibling()
if next_page:
    print(next_page.get('href'))
else:
    print("no page found")
```

**edit**

In response to the comment; this is how I was thinking to use this bit of code. Then it will just be added and you can continue with the loop.

```
def all_match_outcomes():
    for match_outcomes in match_history_url():
        rest_server(True)
        page = requests.get(match_outcomes).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        team_name_element = soup.select_one('div.teamNameHolder')
        team_name = team_name_element.find('h1').text.replace('- Team Overview', '')

        for match_outcome in soup.select('table.simple.gamelist.profilelist tr'):
            opp1 = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'opp1'}).text
            opp2 = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'opp2'}).text

            opp1_score = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'hscore'}).text
            opp2_score = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'ascore'}).text

            if match_outcome(True):  # If teams have past matches
                print(team_name, '%s %s:%s %s' % (opp1, opp1_score, opp2_score, opp2))
        # get the next page if there is one here
       page = paginate.find('a', {'class':'selected'})
       if page:
           next_page = page.find_next_sibling()
           if next_page:
               print(next_page.get('href'))
               # just append this to a list or add it to whatever you use to 
               # track the next url to crawl
               next_url = next_page.get('href')
```

Comment: ok, so do I add my other functions in the if statement? what if the page doesn't have a next page how do I run the rest of my code so It doesn't crash and to obtain the info I need?

Comment: I was thinking you could add it to the code that you have posted here, but I'm not sure what your `match_history_url` function looks like?

Comment: it just loops the url for each team, an example link that it contains is like the one I posted for an example. It holds all the team match url page

Comment: @DJRodrigue so I assume it returns a list? I edited my answer you can just append the next page like that.

Comment: It gives me this error,
page = paginate.find('a', {'class': 'selected'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

its because that team doesnt have those attributes its trying to look for..That what I'm trying to get around. Because some teams do have a next page and some don't, and I believe that the ones that do not have a next page makes it crash..

Comment: @DJRodrigue sorry for the delayed response, I've update the **edit** part of my answer. It's also necessary to check if there's even pagination so it won't error out. Let me know how this works out for you.